# Decent GUI notifications in GNOME

Tags: gnome, email, gui, notifications

I use OS X 10.10.3 here at work, and my colleagues use Fedora 21 with Gnome 3.14.2.

I use apps like Mail and Telegram, and OS X give excellent visual warnings about new messages (numeric badges in the app icon at the dock, sliding notifications that can be set to stay there or disappear, notification center, etc.). But Fedora (as it comes) is terrible to warn them about these things! Both Evolution and Thunderbird show a temporary and tiny message at the bottom, and then it is gone forever. Telegram displays a much bigger message, but it also disappears after some time.

Those problems get even worse because they use two monitors. And some mail/chat messages are really important to be seen as quickly as possible.

We can make some dirty hacks like redirect the mail to Gmail and have a browser plugin to show the alerts, but I was hopping to find something more native. If necessary, we could also try to switch to KDE.

Comment: You can customize gnome-shell notifications via [extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/). Just search for "notifications" on that site and see if you find anything that suits your needs.

Comment: Also note that help is on the way — Gnome 3.16 as featured in Fedora 22 has redesigned notifications. If you're feeling brave, update to the beta and check it out.

Comment: You're confused.  This is not about the *distro*, it's about the [DE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment).

Comment: Yes, I know it is about the desktop environment. Do you recommend another StackExchange site to ask about GUI stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I followed one of the suggestions and went to [gnome.extensions.com](https://extensions.gnome.org). There I found Notifications Alert (blinks the right icons at the top bar) and Panel OSD (which repositions and expands the alerts). They improved the situation a bit.

I'll wait for Gnome 3.16 + Fedora 22 to be stable to see the new notifications. It should be release [soon](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/22/Schedule).